# Question About Visualization of a Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently reading Mendelsohn's Intro to Topology right now. I am chapter 2 which is concerned with metric spaces and I am wondering about the definition of continuity

Definition 3.2 Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$be metric spaces and let $a \in X$. A function $f: X \rightarrow Y $ is said to be continuous at the point $a \in X $ if given $\epsilon > 0 $, there is a $\delta >0$ such that

$ d'(f(x),f(a)) < \delta$

whenever $x \in X$ and

$d(x,a) < \delta$.

My question is of the beginning of the definition where $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ are set as metric spaces. This may be a stupid question, but does this mean that the domain is a metric space in the sense that if we take the first and last element of $X$ and take the absolute value of their difference (which will be the maximum of the set $X$), we get the "length" of the domain so in $\mathbb{R^2}$, this maps out to $Y$ by a function $f$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the first and last element of $X$"? What do you mean by the "difference" of two elements? It sounds like you are assuming that $X$ is a set of real numbers, which need not be the case.

Comment: An abstract metric does *not* involve an absolute value of a difference since there is no notion of subtraction in $X$.

Comment: @RudyMyers I suspect that your textbook states what exactly a "metric space" is. That said, in a nutshell: saying that $(X,d)$ is a metric space means that $X$ is a set of objects where there is some notion of a distance $d(x,y)$ between objects $x,y \in X$.

Comment: OP the comments above explain where you're going slightly wrong with the definition of metric space. Are you also wondering about what it means for a function $f$ to map "from a metric space to another"? (I ask because I got similarly confused when first encountering functions from 'structures' to other structures, rather than functions from 'sets to sets')

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ok so $(X,d)$ being a metric space means that for all objects $x,y$ in this set we can assign a distance function $d(x,y)$ to them? This is from a previous theorem but if we take $maximum d(x_i,y_i)$ we get $X$ itself? So in some sense you could find a metric of $X$ such that its distance is the interval that contains all objects of $X$?

Comment: The definition States that ; If you have two metric spaces and take a point $x$ in first matric space. Function must be continuous at that point if 1). $f(x)$ must be exist. 2). If i will take any $\epsilon$ neighborhood around $f(x)$ then all points lies in that $\epsilon$ nbd. Will only be images of point's lies in $\delta$ neighborhood of $x$ . 3). You can choose any neighborhood , it can be $\delta$ or anything but there must exist a nbd around $x$ which satisfies this property. TRY TO MAKE PICTURE'S ON MIND . HOW WE TAKE TWO MATRIC SPACES AND WHAT'S THE WHOLE PROCEDURE SAYING

Comment: @AmitMittal: please don't shout.

Comment: @Rudy I am not sure what theorem you are referring to, and I have no idea how you could "take maximum $d(x_i,y_i)$ and get $X$ itself". Does the theorem have a name? If not, maybe you could edit your post to add in a statement of the theorem.

Comment: @RobArthan i am really sorry if it sound like i am shouting. But promise i am not .

Comment: @Amit To be a bit more direct, using CAPITALS in text is considered to be the equivalent to shouting and is therefore considered rude.

Comment: The maximum of $d(x,y)$ might not exist, but the supremum will, although it may be $+\infty$. The supremum of $d(x,y)$ is not "$X$ itself", but it is called the ***diameter*** of $X$. If $\sup \{d(x,y)\}=D$, then it is true that all of the elements of $X$ are in any ball of the for $B(x, D)$ for any $x \in X$. Is that what you are thinking of?